# Sending Multiple Commands to device Through SSH

Tags: java, ssh, sshj

I am attempting to send multiple commands to a device using the SSHJ library. There is the option of sending multiple commands in this format:

```
Command command = sshSession.exec("show line; show ip interface brief;");
```

This works, but it is not always usable in my case. I have found other suggestions such as the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23467751/3184104).

When I attempt this suggestion the first command works fine and then it cycles between this error:

```
net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
...
Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
```

or

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.checkConnected(SSHClient.java:713)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.startSession(SSHClient.java:651)
```

The code used is:

```
sshSession = sshClient.startSession();
Command command = sshSession.exec("sho ip int brie");
System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(command.getInputStream()));//Just to see the reply while testing
command.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

sshSession = sshClient.startSession();
Command command2 = sshSession.exec("sho line");
System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(command2.getInputStream()));//Just to see the reply while testing
```

A note if needed, the device I am connecting to, and majority of devices that it will connect to are Cisco networking equipment.

Thank you for any assistance.
-Jarrod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found a resolution for the exact problem. But I worked around the issue by using the DefaultPTY and providing my own streams with all the data I wanted to send. Playing around with [this](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples/RudimentaryPTY.java) example.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the code that worked?