# JSch executing multiple linux commands in one session

Tags: java, shell, ssh, command, jsch

I'm working on a project in which I intend to make a Java GUI application that connects to a ssh server and executes remote commands on the server. I'm willing to use JSch Library. My aim is to make buttons and textfields those will provide the user the ability of sending commands and getting replies easily. I mean, instead of opening xShell and prompting "grep "hi" /usr/file.txt", the user will choose the path from the list and will enter "hi" into the textfield and will press the button for grep.

Problem is, I couldn't find a solution to execute multiple linux commands in one session (I don't want shell if i cannot redirect its input and output streams) (also I don't want the solution "cd.. \n dir \n ls -l" which works fine but not solving my problem)  send the arguments those shall be taken from related GUI components.

Since I have not made so much modifications on the JSch's example code, yet, you can see the code here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Thanks from now on.

Comment: `shell` is the way to go.

Comment: @ScaryWombat hi, can i redirect shell's input and output stream to my GUI components, then? if yes, how? thanks from now on.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do directly, but to redirect to a String and then update your GUI from the String is easy enough

Comment: The sample program which you link to is perfectly capable of running a sequence of multiple commands. In fact, the program's default is a two-command pipeline. You say the "cd.. \n dir \n ls -l" solution works fine but doesn't solve your problem. What _is_ your problem?

Comment: @Kenster for example, when the user wants to change to a directory from the directory list, selects a file  and make a grep search in that file , --("cd ..") --("grep hi smp.txt"), in first step his path changes but in second step the path is reset(because exec channel does so). so how can I solve it?

Comment: I suggest you to consider using an Expect-like library. Take a look at my answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24604951/3537858

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov I will check it immediately, thanks from now on.

Comment: This limitation is RIDICULOUS!

Answer (score 0):

If using `exec` type of channel you can combine commands with && :

```
channel.setCommand(". ./.profile && env");
```